# Issue in Sync with soft delete enabled in native iOS (Azure Mobile services)

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services, soft-delete

I am using azure mobile services on iOS platform and syncing with service ( soft delete enabled), when I delete some records using another device, _delete flag is set to true for that records in service database, but when I sync with iOS device, deleted records are still present there .

I have seen other questions on SO, but they did not solve my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :** 
I am using enableSoftDelete:true

```
 DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TableName>(context, Request, Services, enableSoftDelete: true);
```

A new column _Deleted is setting to true after deleting from another device.

Comment: Are you using a Node backend or a .NET one?

Comment: @lindydonna-msft I am using .NET backend for Service.

Answer (score 1):

To enable soft delete on the .NET backend, you need to pass a parameter to the EntityDomainManager in your controller InitializeMethod:

```
    DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request, Services, enableSoftDelete: true);
```

For more information, see [Using soft delete in Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-using-soft-delete/#enabling-soft-delete-for-the-net-backend).

Comment: To help debug, what happens when you send a REST request directly, adding __includeDeleted=true?

Comment: Deleted records are coming in the response after making rest request using _includeDeleted=true. So what should I try to make proper sync request ?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a Deleted column in the local Core Data model. That can interfere with the SDK.

Comment: I tried after deleting the ms_Deleted column, but the result is same. It is not showing correct output.

Comment: @superB did you ever get an answer to this? I am facing similar issues. Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I cannot find documentation regarding this feature. I'm trying to delete 15k items from the database using soft delete. will it delete from the client device?